# TOMCAT 7.0.92 with JDK 11 :- ERROR localhost-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig - Unable to process Jar tools.jar for annotations

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, java-11

We have a web application running on Tomcat server container. Web application is compiled and using JDK 11 as runtime JRE for execution purpose.

> Tomcat Version : - 7.0.92 JDK Version :-  11
>
> Problem Description :- 
>   1.We are seeing the errors in tomcat log regarding jar scanning at time of Tomcat server startup.
>   2. Once Tomcat server is getting launched through our web application, it searches the Tools.jar for annotations purpose.
>   3. As we all know, JDK 11 has stopped shipping / bundling JRE which contains the tools.jar,  Tomcat server reports an error which is
>   following :--

```
ERROR localhost-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig - Unable to process Jar [jar:file:/ C:/JDK11/lib/tools.jar!/] for annotations
 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\JDK11\lib\tools.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:194)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1763)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1222)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:824)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource$FinalizableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:850)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:839)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:346)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.FileUrlJar.<init>(FileUrlJar.java:48)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1957)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1932)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5566)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

> Resolution / workaround applied :-  Post extensive search on Google
>   and other community, We found that a property is suggested to be
>   applied in the catalina.properties file which would help avoiding the
>   scanning of all the jars.
>                                                                   **org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=*.jar** We have this property already in place and even this has not helped resolving
>   this issue.

Therefore, we request you to kindly provide some insight / working resolution of this issue. Please revert in case any more info is required.

Appreciate your co-operation !

Comment: You should match your Tomcat to the JVM it runs on.  Try Tomcat 9

Answer (score 4):

Either **downgrade** your JDK to JDK 8 (tools.jar was removed in JDK 9), or try **upgrading** your tomcat version to version 8 or 9.

I dont see a reason for using an old version of tomcat when there are other stable releases (tomcat 7 was declared stable in **2011!**). Avoid mixing old and new technologies, as they drift apart from each other, like in your case.

An old version of tomcat will not be compatible with a new version of java.

Long story short, try out tomcat 8 or 9.

Comment: Either mark it as a comment or else do elaborate on the *why part*.

Comment: I think the why part is Tomcat 7 (very very old) does not support Java 11 (something new)

Comment: Good answer, but a reason is that a managed operating system like RHEL / CentOS 7 includes Java 11, but the newest Tomcat offered is version 7 (I'm guessing due to some jboss competition, unfortunately).